square plots with identical x and y axes in python
I am plotting (x,y) pairs of data and I need to plot them in square plots with equal x and y axes. I need scale and even formatting of the axes to be identical. I have used
ax.set_aspect(np.diff(ax.get_xlim())/np.diff(ax.get_ylim()), adjustable='box')

which seems to be working fine. My problem is I am not getting the identical tick spacings and ticklabel formatting in x and y axes even though I assigned equal datalimits for both axes.
I cannot give fixed axis limits or tick spacings as the data range keeps varying as shown in the image.
Is there any way to ensure identical axes for my plots?

I also tried to use  mticker.AutoLocator() but I could not get what I wanted.
